# When trying to play Polish VOD Edge is showing an error that points to a non-existing website

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-11-v22h2

I am trying to play [Polish VOD television](https://playnow.pl/). Works like a charm in Chrome and Firefox (though you need to have a paid account and authenticate yourself). When trying to play exactly the same movie, serie, channel, whatever in Microsoft Edge, I am ending up with "never-ending loader".

Jumping into console reveals following error:

[image]

> Chrome is blocking notification permission requests on this site because the site tends to show permission requests that mislead, trick, or force users into allowing notifications. You should fix the issues as soon as possible and submit your site for another review. Learn more at https://permanently-removed.invalid/webtools/answer/9799048.

When I click that link, I am getting 404 of course, because domain shown in Edge's error is naturally *invalid*.

**What am I missing here? Is this a bug in Edge?**

What is the point in telling you that any website has any kind of problems in source code and then suggesting you that you should visit an invalid an non-existing service to revalidate your website?

Comment: Error messages in the Developer Console are intended for developers, not for you. Even with that link working you wouldn't be able to do anything about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is described in the article
[Broken push notification on Edge 107 @ Windows 11](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/broken-push-notification-on-edge-107-windows-11/m-p/3667303)
from Nov 01, 2022. It was for Chrome on that date, as you can see that
Microsoft failed even to replace the word "Chrome" in the message.

This same error was at that time reported also to arrive in Apple
with a similar but not identical invalid link.

As Edge is built upon the code-base of Chromium, this seems like a bug
that was since fixed in Chrome, but that is still found in Edge.
Microsoft might in the future apply the same fix to Edge (or not).

Your only possible action is to file a bug-report on the Windows
Feedback Hub and wait for Microsoft to fix it. In the meantime
you have no choice but to use another browser for such websites.

The author has claimed that refreshing the problem page multiple times
may cause Edge to block this site's push notifications, as can be seen
in "Site Permissions" settings. Possibly when this will happen,
the error message might disappear.